# C# String Trimming with ServiceStack/ORMLite

Tags: c#, string, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

i'm using servicestack and retrieving data from DB with ORMLite.
Some of the DB's rows are strings and some of them needs to be whitespaces-trimmed before they are sended to the client like:

```
    {... ,"folderCode":"5150001     ",....}
```

Does ORMLite offer a way to trim strings during object mapping? Or does ServiceStack offer a way to trim strings during serialization?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

If you only need this done on a few specific properties of a class, you can use the `OnSerializingFn`.

Given a `DummyClass` with a `FolderCode` property that you want serialized

```
public class DummyClass
{
    public string FolderCode { get; set; }
}
```

Then override the `OnSerializingFn`

```
JsConfig<DummyClass>.OnSerializingFn = obj =>
{
    obj.FolderCode = obj.FolderCode.Trim();
    return obj;
};
```

Comment: The reason you would need to do this (override the serialization of the DTO type instead of overriding serialization of `string` itself) is that [ServiceStack.Text uses a special `JsonUtils.WriteString` method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Text/JsonSerializer.cs#L71) for string types, silently ignoring any potential `OnSerializingFn` or other per-type custom serializing code, presumably for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks it looks good but in this way i should do it for each object. I have hundreds of Classes and some of them have strings that need to be trimmed. Wouldn't it be slow?
Is there a way to do it with Annotations or similar?